# Infopath 2013 Buttons

Tags: sharepoint-2013, infopath

We have developed a form that is being used via SharePoint 2013.  We would like the audience to be able to click on a list item to open up the InfoPath form and then when in the InfoPath form, press on the created buttons to load different views of the form and hide/show certain sections....without it being in Edit mode.

The premise being that the end user has an interactive form that is quick and easy to use upon loading.

Is there any way that a user can activate the rules applied to the buttons in Read mode or does Edit mode always have to be activated first?

Many thanks in advance for any hints or tips!

Answer (score 0):

Well technically you can create a Read-Only form by making all the Pages Read-Only in their settings and use data connections to pull the data into the form fields you want.

So I would make a landing page with buttons that would change the view, run a query and set fields values that you want to display for each Read-Only page/view.